# input type password value?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, input

hello i have a problem with the following issue:

i have two input fields. one is for the login username i.e. and the other one is the password. now i would like to set the value of both fields. my problem is the password. my intend to realize that is the following:

HTML:

```
<input 
type="text"
id="log_password" 
name="log_password" 
value="<?php echo ($log_password);?>" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value='';this.type='password'"
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
```

PHP:

```
$log_password = "Password";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $log_password = $_POST['log_password'];

        if(empty($log_password)){
            $errors['log_password'][]="No password given";
            $_POST['log_password'] = "Password";
            $log_password = $_POST['log_password'];
    }       
}
```

the problem is that this works up to the point where the form will be submitted. in case of an error the password is visible again because of the `type="text"` tag. so how can i solve this, if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="small2"> 
<?php if (!isset($errors['log_password'])):?>
<input 
type="<?= $passwordVal == "" ? "text" : "password" ?>" 
id="log_password" name="log_password" 
value="<?php echo ($log_password);?>" 
placeholder="Passwort" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='Passwort')this.value=''" 
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if (isset($errors['log_password'])):?>
<input class="log-err" 
type="<?= $passwordVal == "" ? "text" : "password" ?>" 
id="log_password" name="log_password" 
value="<?php echo ($log_password);?>" 
placeholder="Passwort" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='Passwort')this.value=''" 
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a proper `<label>` element. Don't abuse the `value` attribute.

Comment: @Quentin I'd like to point out that `<label>` is not always necessary if `placeholder` attribute is used. It is, however, recommended that each `<input>` have a `<label>` which corresponds to it.

Comment: @Matt — From the specification: *The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.* and *The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format.*

Comment: @Quentin +1 for one-upping me. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt correctly suggest, you can use **placeholder** tag.

But to get placeholder working, you cannot set "value". The solution is using conditional type, of course, or playing with jQuery framework. You can do something like this..

```
<?
    $your_pass = 'bla-bla-bla';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
        <!-- Load jQuery library from Google repository -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="password" name="log_password" id="log_password" />
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            /* execute this by jQuery when document is ready */

            /* must use traditional javascript to change input's type attribute */
            document.getElementById('log_password').setAttribute('type', 'text');

            /* set empty value attribute of input with id "log_password" */
            $('input#log_password').attr('val','');

            /* set placeholder attribute */
            $('input#log_password').attr('placeholder','Password');

            $('input#log_password').focus(function(){
                /* when input with id log_password is focus.. */
                $(this).attr('placeholder','');

                /* set the value as you prefer... */
                $(this).val('<?=$your_pass?>');

                /* reset type of input to password */
                document.getElementById('log_password').setAttribute('type', 'password');
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: hello, i think your solution would be the best way to handle this. i have never been working with jquery before. would you be that friendly and could comment every line? i still look for parallels to javascript but i cant see where the function will be called... the php variable is also not understandable. thanks.

Comment: I add some comments. Remember that this is only an example, for show you how you can play with DOM by jQuery... For do what you need, maybe you must combine php and jQuery. You can find manual and a lot of examples on [jQuery official site](http://jquery.com); belive me: it's really a simple framework.
Just a last note: as @Quentin said: don't abuse of placeholder tag! In this case, can be better use simply a label and leave input as password field.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" ... />
```

If you ***MUST*** use this as a text field (in order to display "Password") you should make the input type conditional:

```
<?php
    // in case of error, the value that the user entered will be passed back via GET (POST?)
    $passwordVal = isset($_GET['log_password']) ? $_GET['log_password'] : "";
?>

<!-- if ($passwordVal) is an empty string, type is "text", else type is "password". -->
<input type="<?= $passwordVal == "" ? "text" : "password" ?>" ... />
```

Comment: and what about the text type for the value? this should be readable.

Comment: @bonny Password should never be readable - it should be obfuscated with asterisks.  The `placeholder` attribute will allow "Password" to be visible to the user until the focus is given to that input (as long as it has no assigned value).

Comment: this does not work. the value="password" is not visible on loading the page

Comment: @bonny In that case, you're using an old browser which doesn't support HTML5; use a `<label>` instead.

Comment: no, there is not enough space for it. it has to be the value. here is an example how it works: https://www.rapidshare.com/ as you can see the code works. but i'm not able to read out the source code to find out how it works.

Comment: @bonny I don't have access to that website from my office; by "not enough space" do you mean the input is too small (or has a size limit) or there isn't enough room for the `<label>`?

Comment: there is not enough room between both input fields. the layout wont be changed.

Comment: @bonny `$passwordVal` is simply the default value for that input if it's been passed. It will be determined by $_POST or $_GET (depending on which method you're using).

Comment: okay... using this also does not work. maybe i'm a little confused about the short if-statement form. i updated my question with the temporarily used code.

Comment: If there isn't enough space, then fix the design so there is enough space.

Comment: @Quentin: Not everyone has the ability to "change the design". In a perfect world this would be possible but there are people who don't have the power to make those decisions and have to live within the limits placed by someone above them.

Answer (score 0):

I think , you need change type from 'text' to 'password' , if has errors

Answer (score 0):

write the code you regarded as a function and then call it with loading the page, focus event and blur event.
The solution of Matt is nice but I think it restricted to HTML5 Supported browsers.

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more accessible to non-html5 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

how about a script on document ready to check if log_password value is password and change the type.

oh sorry dint see deste's post +1 for that